# My column get ambigous while use using and on in the same query in SQL I got ambigous at employee_id in line 4

Tags: sql, join, using, self-join

```
SELECT m.employee_id, m.first_name, m.last_name
FROM employees e
JOIN employees m ON (e.manager_id = m.employee_id)
JOIN job_history USING (employee_id)
WHERE job_id LIKE 'A%';
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the **concrete RDBMS** you're using

Comment: It's pretty obvious why the program is confused.  People are confused you.  When you say `USING(employee_id)`, is it the `employee_id` of `e` or `m`?

Answer (score 0):

Which table does this EMPLOYEE_ID belong to? Apply table aliases to all columns, always.

```
SELECT m.employee_id, m.first_name, m.last_name
FROM employees e
JOIN employees m 
ON (e.manager_id = m.employee_id)
JOIN job_history 
USING (employee_id)            --> this?
WHERE job_id LIKE 'A%';        --> ... and this would also benefit from an alias
```

Answer (score 0):

Qualify *all* column names in the query.  When you use `using`, you do not need to qualify the names of the keys used for the `join`.

Then, `using` uses *all* matching column names.  I think you want to be specific about which tables the columns are coming from:

```
SELECT m.employee_id, m.first_name, m.last_name
FROM employees e JOIN
     employees m
     ON e.manager_id = m.employee_id JOIN
     job_history jh
     ON jh.employee_id = ?.employee_id  -- Is this for the manager or the employee?
WHERE jf.job_id LIKE 'A%';
```